# How to pass a list as separate arguments to a mixin in SASS?

Tags: variables, sass, compass-sass, mixins

I'm having some elements that are using a compass shadow mixin. As the arguments are the same I want to have them in a variable. I thought this is what [variable arguments](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_arguments) are for, but obviously I'm doing something wrong as the following does not work:

```
// my shadow style
$shadow: #000000, 0px, 0px, 20px;

.list {
    @include single-box-shadow($shadow...);
}
```

This should be the same as

```
.list {
    @include single-box-shadow(#000000, 0px, 0px, 20px);
}
```

But while the second example works, the first one is compiling to

```
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Compass version is 0.12.2 and SASS is 3.2.3.

**edit: I'm compiling with yeoman, maybe it uses a different (older) version? How can I check that?**

Comment: Both examples compile the same for me... What version of Compass and Sass are you using?

Comment: Compass is 0.12.2 and Sass is 3.2.3.

Comment: I'm compiling with yeoman, don't know if this makes any difference - should use the system compass and sass version?

Comment: It should be noted that `box-shadow` expects a list of values that are separated by spaces, not commas.

Comment: Thanks cimmanon, but as I mentionend it also works with a comma separated list. (I am using `single-box-shadow` and not `box-shadow`)

Answer (score 0):

The `single-box-shadow` mixin does not use variable arguments (see: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/box_shadow/#mixin-single-box-shadow).

When you invoke the mixin using your variable, what you're essentially doing is this:

```
@include single-box-shadow((#000000, 0px, 0px, 20px));
```

The entire list is being passing as the first argument of the mixin: `$color`.  If you want to reuse specific box-shadow values either use the `box-shadow` mixin with a space delimited list or create your own custom box-shadow mixin.

Comment: Thank you. And how would I do that? The compass docu is really bad. I tried `$shadow: $black 0px 0px 20px;` and `@include box-shadow($shadow);` which also just echoed a "none" shadow.

Comment: Have you tried compiling it without Yeoman?  That compiled fine for me using `compass watch`.  Though, looking at the version history, Yeoman would have to have a *very* old version for this to not work as it should.